# The greatest possible geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Wikipedia claims that

"*Given an n×n matrix A.... both algebraic and geometric multiplicity are integers between (including) 1 and n.*"

But how can the geometric multiplicity possibly be n? Since $(A-\lambda I)$ is a square matrix (as opposed to a matrix with more columns than rows), each of A's eigenspaces $Nul (A-\lambda I)$  has at most $(n-1)$ dimensions, isn't it?

I.e. The *geometric* multiplicity of an eigenvalue must be a number between between $1$ and $(n-1)$, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $A=\lambda I$, then $A-\lambda I=0$, and the null matrix obviously has kernel dimension $n$.

Comment: And, of course, that's the only example where the geometric multiplicity is $n$.

Comment: @celtschk Oh yes, of course! Thanks!! Thanks, Robert, too.