# Can an eigenvalue (of an $n$ by $n$ matrix A) with algebraic multiplicity $n$ have an eigenspace with fewer than $n$ dimensions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is it possible for a matrix with characteristic polynomial $(λ−a)^3$ to have an eigenline (one-dimensional eigenspace)?

I know that geometric multiplicity can generally be smaller than algebraic multiplicity. But I was wondering if algebraic multiplicity $n$ might be a special case. This question is motivated by my earlier one [The greatest possible geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/179798/21813), where I learnt that $A$ has an $n$-dimensional eigenspace iff. $A=\lambda I$.

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked quite a few questions recently.
I wanted to make sure that you are aware about the quotas 50
questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan
posting your questions accordingly.
(If you try to post more questions, stackexchange software will not
allow you to do so.)
For more details see
[meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4742/should-we-ask-for-question-quotas-like-those-that-have-been-available-for-the-bi/4770#4770).

Comment: @Martin Thanks, am now made aware. Don't think I will be near hitting the limit though. And I will try to be judicious. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. Consider the matrix 
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
which has a single eigenvalue $1$ of multiplicity $2$, yet the only solutions to the equation
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\
y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} x +y \\
y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} x \\
y\end{pmatrix}$$
come when $y=0$, and so the eigenspace is $1$-dimensional.

Comment: Note that the same type of example (an upper-triangular matrix of all ones) works for any $n$.

Comment: Thanks! Small typo in your answer, I think (missing the scalar multiple on the RHS of the second eqn)

Comment: @Ryan Since the scalar is $1$, it can be omitted. :)

Comment: Weren't you equating $Ax=kx$? Oh nevermind, this is inconsequential.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Take for example
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
whose characteristic polynomial is $(\lambda-1)^3$, but whose eigenspace is one-dimensional (spanned by $(1,0,0)$.)

If the matrix is symmetric, this can't happen though. (This is a nice exercise to show.)

Answer (score 1):

Algebraic multiplicity $n$ is not a special case. Take the following operator for example:

$$
T(w, z) = (z, 0)
$$

It has the following matrix in the standard base:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The characteristic polynomial is $z^2$. Yet, $\operatorname{null}T$ is one-dimensional (spanned by $(1, 0)$).

Algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue $\lambda$ is equal to $\operatorname{null}(T - \lambda I)^{\operatorname{dim}V}$. In this example, $\operatorname{null}T^2$ does indeed have 2 dimensions.